# How to set full screen in Android Vision API?

Tags: java, android

I want to create a barcode scanner that uses full screen.
I used google's vision API samples that can be found [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision)

This is my result:

[image]

I want to make a preview of the camera to the full height, how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CameraSourcePreview.java find this if condition and change it to:

```
if (childHeight < layoutHeight) {
childHeight = layoutHeight;
childWidth = (int)(((float) layoutHeight / (float) height) * width);
}
```

If you want to match parent for width and height you can use

`childHeight = layoutHeight;
 childWidth = layoutWidth;`